# React Native button on press doesn't work properly

Tags: react-native, redux

I got a weird problem on my react native app, I've a counter buttons, like increment and decrement the quantity of product using redux, but the problem is when i press on button the store value change but the Text component (View) doesn't change automatically until i click outside the button (That's the weird issue).

I tried Button component with onPress, TouchableOpacity onPress but still the same issue.

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.handleDecQuantity(item)}}>
 <Icon
  family="AntDesign"
  size={16}
  name="minus"
  color="#2B4D8E"
  style={styles.btn}
 />
</TouchableOpacity>
...
<Text size={16}>{item.quantity}</Text>
...
<Button onlyIcon icon="plus" radius={3} shadowless iconFamily="AntDesign" iconSize={20} color="tarnsparent" iconColor="#2B4D8E" style={styles.btn}  onPress={()=>{this.handleIncQuantity(item)}}>+</Button>
```

I hope the issue is clear, The counter change only when i click outside of button or TouchableOpacity

Comment: could you give more code, such as your Text component

Comment: Ok i've updated the post @Lenoarod

Comment: item.quantity is what, I think it should be a state type.

Comment: item is returned from redux store, and when i click button it's changing successfully but doesn't show the incremented value till i click outside the button